# Is it required to add org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener for tomcat 8 server.xml?

Tags: java, tomcat8

I am upgrading to tomcat 8 from 7. Is it required to add this listener?

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know this listener prints the application server and OS informations.
It should be the first on the list of listeners included in the `<Server>` element but can be **ommited**.

Comment: Thanks man, I just wanted to confirm if its mandatory or not.

Comment: Just commenting this line or deleting it solves this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to speed up the startup,it can be noted.